# How to update the user password, the user belongs to some tenant? Not from Admin carbon UI

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

How to update the user password, the user belongs to some tenant. Is there any WSO2 Admin api is available? For example the user is like testuser@wso2.apl. I want to update the user password using some api or wso2 admin web service.
If any one is having idea on this, Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use RemoteUserStoreManagerService admin service.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs#ManagingUsersandRoleswithAPIs-updateCredentialByAdmin()

Comment: Thank you. This api is able to update the password for Tenant user.